# How to calculate $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\tan^{-1}\left(x^2\right)\sin(x)}{x^2+y^2} = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

$$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\tan^{-1}\left(x^2\right)\sin(x)}{x^2+y^2} = 0$$

I know limit exists and it's equal to $0$, but don't know how to get desired result.

Hints are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: You can obtain an upper bound for $|f(x,y)-0|$ that still tends to zero. One ingredient could be that $\arctan x^2 \leq x^2 \leq x^2+y^2$

Comment: @PierreCarre Yes, looks about right, then we are left with sin(x) which is 0 at (x, y) = (0, 0). Thanks.

Comment: That's it! And the result I mentioned is quite easy to prove with elementary calculus,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to (a,b)} f(x,y) = c \Leftrightarrow \lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)}|f(x,y)-c| = 0
$$

So, if you are able to show that for $(x,y)$ in some neighbourhood of $(a,b)$ you have that $|f(x,y)-c| \leq g(x,y)$ and that $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)} g(x,y)=0$, you will have shown that $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)} f(x,y)=c$. In the specific case you present, you just need to get a bound on $\arctan(x^2)$ and you'll get rid of the zero denominator.

Comment: This is my idea: $\forall (x, y) \in \mathbb{R^2}, (x, y) \neq (0, 0)$ holds: 

$0 \le |\frac{\tan^{-1}\left(x^2\right) \sin(x)}{x^2 + y^2}  - 0| \le |\frac{(x^2 + y^2) \sin(x)}{x^2 + y^2}| = \sin(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $(x, y) \rightarrow (0, 0)$.

Comment: @meerkat that's just perfect, if you change it to $|\sin x|$.

Comment: Yes, right. Thanks.